# R- Welch Two Sample t-test (t.test) interpretation help

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I calculated a Welch two sample t-test in R and am very confused on how to interpret my results. The calculation was based off of a very small dataset (two groups each with 7 samples). The "alternative hypothesis" line is especially throwing me off. Looking to determine if there is a significant difference between the averages of the two groups.

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  lizard$cold and lizard$warm
t = -1.7796, df = 10.147, p-value = 0.1051
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.2742915  0.4742915
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.894286  7.794286
```

Comment: The null (baseline) hypothesis for this test is that the two means, of something related to "cold" and "warm" lizards I assume, are the same.  The alternative is that the two means are different.  This latter statement expands to "the difference in means is not equal to 0", which means the same as "the difference between the two means is not equal to 0", but is slightly more grammatically correct: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106642/definition-of-differentiate-difference-in-and-difference-between...

Comment: The p-value is 0.1051, which is not typically considered sufficiently small for statistical significance.

Comment: The line in the output is not telling whether they differ, it's explaining the alternative hypothesis your code caused to be tested (though I don't like the particular phrasing there myself). To decide whether to reject the null, you could compare the p-value with your significance level (reject if it's less than or equal to the significance level).

Answer (score 4):

The t-test is testing two competing hypotheses:

$$H_0: \text{There is no difference between the (true) averages of the two groups}$$

$$\text{versus}$$

$$H_a: \text{There is a difference between the (true) averages of the two groups}.$$

It is not clear what averages you are comparing for the two groups (e.g., average weights), so I stated the two hypotheses in a vague fashion – you will need to fill in the missing information yourself.

The p-value associated with the test is `0.1051`, so we cannot reject the null hypothesis ($H_0$) of no difference between the (true) averages of the two groups since the p-value is greater than the usual significance level `alpha = 0.05`. Based on these data, we conclude that there is not enough evidence of a difference between the (true) averages of the two groups at the usual significance level of `alpha = 0.05`. (You might want to consider a larger significance level of `alpha = 0.10` with such small sample sizes, though.)

The conclusion holds provided the assumptions underlying the test are verified by the data. See [Wikipedia: Welch's t-test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) for details on the test assumptions.

Here, the word "true" is used to refer to the averages you would get in each group if you had access to all the possible samples, not just the 7 samples per group you included in your study.

Comment: You're welcome, Victoria! You should compute and compare the standard deviations of the two groups to see if you really need to assume different variability in each group. If the standard deviations are roughly comparable, then you should set the option var.equal of t.test to TRUE when performing the t-test.

Comment: Or maybe you should decide, which t-test to use, before you look at the data because some would consider everything else cheating.

Comment: $H_0$ is not "there is no difference" but rather that no significant difference was detected. Big mistake, often used to make spurious claims. I repeat for clarity, NOT SIGNIFICANT is not "insignificant." The experimenter's inability to detect a significant difference is often due to not having enough data to detect one, as distinct from there not being a difference. For that reason, confidence intervals for differences should be stated, not just probabilities. For example, if you do not detect a significant difference between the heights of men and women, and the confidence interval

Comment: cont... for a difference in height for men versus women is between -10 cm to +20 cm 95% of the time, what you need is more data and not that there is no difference in height.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually widespread confusion about how to interpret p-values, even among scientists. I recommend the [ASA Statement on Statistical Significance and P-Values](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108) and [Greenland et al. (2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10654-016-0149-3) as references.

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  lizard$cold and lizard$warm
t = -1.7796, df = 10.147, p-value = 0.1051
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.2742915  0.4742915
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.894286  7.794286
```

`t = -1.7796` is the calculated t-statistic. `df = 10.147` are the degrees of freedom. These are each calculated according to their own formulas and used with a t-distribution to derive `p-value = 0.1051`

`p-value = 0.1051` assumes that all your assumptions are true *and* that you didn't mess up the research design, sampling, etc. *and* that $H_0$ is true, and tells you:

- Given that there is no actual/true difference in means, if you were to repeat your experiment over and over again, 10.51% of the time you would see the type of difference in means as in your samples, *or a more extreme difference in means*.

This tells you something about how compatible your data is with a statistical model that assumes the true group means are actually equal.

Typically you want the $H_0$ model to be incompatible with the data. Lower p-values mean less compatible.

When a p-value is low enough, i.e. lower than 0.05, researchers will often call it "significant". If the p-value is not low enough ($p>0.05$), researchers will often call it "not significant".

```
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.2742915  0.4742915
```

This tells you that, given that you assume $H_0$ is false, the true mean
*may* lie in the interval [-4.2742915, 0.4742915].

It's called a 95% confidence interval because, if you repeat your experiment over and over again, 95% of the time the interval *will contain* the true mean.

It's an interval that you can have some confidence about containing the true mean (given that all your assumptions are correct).

However, you should use `alternative="greater"` or `alternative="less"`, e.g,  `t.test(..., alternative="less")`, if you want to test if the mean of `lizard$warm` is greater or less than the mean of `lizard$cold`. The [default behavior](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test) of `t.test` is two-tailed, which might not be what you want.